# Convert date in form of "%Y%M%D" to "%Y%M%D%H%M%S" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my dataframe

```
   Date Time   Open   High    Low  Close     Volume  Adj Close
0 2012-05-15  15.90  16.06  15.80  16.02  134454.78       0.08
1 2012-05-16  16.00  16.00  15.75  15.76  150305.11      -0.26
2 2012-05-17  15.80  15.97  15.76  15.94  133389.98       0.18
3 2012-05-18  15.80  15.91  15.66  15.72  157863.19      -0.22
4 2012-05-21  15.72  15.84  15.70  15.77   85694.85       0.05
```

You see in the column of "Date Time", the data is in this form"%Y%M%D"
I want to convert them to be "%Y%M%D%H%M$S" which is for example `2012-05-17 00:00:00`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not already you need to convert to datetime, then you can call `apply` and use `datetime.strftime` to do the formatting:

```
In [212]:

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date']
Out[212]:
index
0   2012-05-15
1   2012-05-16
2   2012-05-17
3   2012-05-18
4   2012-05-21
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
In [213]:

import datetime as dt
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df['Date']
Out[213]:
index
0    2012-05-15 00:00:00
1    2012-05-16 00:00:00
2    2012-05-17 00:00:00
3    2012-05-18 00:00:00
4    2012-05-21 00:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Note that this converts the dtype from datetime to str

Answer (score -2):

Please go through this, I know its not the exact answer but it might help you.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

Comment: Please don't post link only answers, you need to provide code and an explanation